# Create R plot containing multiple panels where each panel is saved as .png/.pdf

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a big plot which contains four subplots made by plot() function. 
All the subplots are saved as png/pdf file format.
Is there way in R to import these plots to R then create a big plot that contains all the subplots?

Comment: If you still have the code used to generate the original plots, you might be better off just making a plot with multiple panels in R and saving the whole thing to png. See: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html for some info on combining plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it not be easier to fix the problem at source by creating each plot, laying them out together then saving them as one file? The `grid` layout functions should work with the base `plot` function as far as I can tell. Here's a simple example using `ggplot2`. If you use `ggplot` you could perhaps also use the facet functions. Code follows after image.

[image: screenshot]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

set.seed(23456)
mydf <- data.frame(mydate = seq(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2012-12-01'), by = '1 month'),
                   run1 = runif(12, 100, 200),
                   run2 = runif(12, 300, 400),
                   run3 = runif(12, 1000, 2000),
                   run4 = runif(12, 2000, 3000))

p1 <- ggplot(data = mydf) +
         geom_line(aes(x = mydate, y = run1))

p2 <- ggplot(data = mydf) +
         geom_line(aes(x = mydate, y = run2))

p3 <- ggplot(data = mydf) +
         geom_line(aes(x = mydate, y = run3))

p4 <- ggplot(data = mydf) +
         geom_line(aes(x = mydate, y = run4))


png(filename = paste("multipleplot.png", sep = ""), width = 600, height = 600, units = "px", res = NA)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2, widths = c(300, 300))))

vplayout <- function(x, y)
    viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

print(p1, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(p2, vp = vplayout(1,2))
print(p3, vp = vplayout(2,1))
print(p4, vp = vplayout(2,2))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'grImport' package has functions to read pdf files, convert to RGML and then import for use within the grid graphics framework.

The 'png' package has a `readPNG` function.

And as thelatemail is suggesting if you have both the data and the code that created these plots, you may want either to look at the `layout` function or to use `par` with arguments mfrow, mfcol, or mfg.